# Temperature change when mixing different ratios of NaOH and H2SO4 solutions

Tags: acid-base, thermodynamics

Under the same conditions, mixing how many ml of 1M $\ce{KOH}$ solution and 0.5M $\ce{H2SO4}$ solutions to form a total volume of 100ml produces a rise in temperature?

Comment: If there is already the tag thermodynamics, the title thermodynamics question carries literally zero additional information, like a book title "The Adventure book" in the bookstore section "Adventure books". // The question itself as the English sentence is formulated in very confused way, words almost in a random order and it is  not trivial to guess wht is asked. // Note that questions looking like homework/test/exam/lab questions/tasks without written *significant* resolving attempts are *explicitly off-topic* on this site and will be closed.

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  down-voting or closure.

Comment: What is the question  ? Is the "rise in temp" to be read as "rise of temperature" ?

Comment: @Maurice Or "What volumes...?".  It is not a question, it is a riddle or encrypted message.

Answer (score 1):

What you've asked is a neutralisation reaction. Any amount of acid and base mixed together would cause a neutralisation reaction, and in general, neutralisation reactions are highly exothermic reactions:

$$\ce{H+ + OH- -> H2O}$$

The enthalpy change for this reaction is $\Delta_\mathrm{r} H = 57.62$ $  \mathrm{kJ/mol}$, which is pretty high. Also since both of your reactants are strong electrolytes, your heat of neutralisation is not pH dependent.

So, mixing any amount of the acid and the base to create a $100$ ml solution would cause a rise in temperature.

Comment: I don't think this answer totally covers the question. The molar enthalpy of generic acid-base reaction is useful but not fully explanatory.